# Ionic4 ion-slide, not working property when loop config is on

Tags: angular, ionic4, swiper.js, ngzone

With simple reproduction

```
config = {
...
loop: true,
...
}

<ion-slides (options)="config">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3]">
    <div (click)="clickedMe()">Content goes here</div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

clickMe() {
  console.log('hey me clicked');
}
```

Loop is not working properly. Actually because of loop we should see 4th item, (which is actually first one) but click event is not firing.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

```
  slideOptsOne = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: {
      disableOnInteraction: false,
      loop :true,
    },
  };
```

This is the new config and works like charm :)
Happy coding